# How To speed up postgresql self join query

Tags: postgresql

I am using join on the same table to get 50 rows at a time, but it takes 20 secs to get back 50 rows.

```
Select Distinct ON (S1.service) S1.account,S1.stid,S1.receiver,S1.identifier,
       S1.binfo,S2.dlr_mask,S2.time,S1.msgdata,S1.msg_cost 
from sql_sent_sms S1 
left join sql_sent_sms S2 
       on S1.service = S2.service  
where  S2.time Between :senttime and :endtime 
  and S1.userid=:userid 
Order By S1.service");
```

I have created index on `time , service ,userid`  parameter.

But it didnt helped much.

what else should i do to speed up .

This is the result of analysing the query

```
       EXPLAIN ANALYZE Select Distinct ON (S1.service) S1.account,S1.stid,S1.receiver,S1.identifier,S1.binfo,S2.dlr_mask,S2.time,S1.msgdata,S1.msg_cost
               from sql_sent_sms S1
               left join sql_sent_sms S2
                      on S1.service = S2.service
               where  S2.time Between '1459759193' and '1459849193'
                 and S1.userid='10412144'
               Order By S1.service , S2.dlr_mask asc limit 50;
                                                                              QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=56635220.85..56938614.70 rows=50 width=308) (actual time=1.177..1.177 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=56635220.85..57035700.74 rows=66 width=308) (actual time=1.176..1.176 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=56635220.85..56835460.79 rows=80095977 width=308) (actual time=1.176..1.176 rows=0 loops=1)
               Sort Key: s1.service, s2.dlr_mask
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.24..127912.78 rows=80095977 width=308) (actual time=1.166..1.166 rows=0 loops=1)
                     ->  Index Scan using idx_sentmsgbydate on sql_sent_sms s1  (cost=0.43..21247.62 rows=5765 width=292) (actual time=0.035..0.091 rows=34 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((userid)::text = '10412144'::text)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using idx_sentmsgandstauts on sql_sent_sms s2  (cost=0.81..18.45 rows=5 width=126) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=0 loops=34)
                           Index Cond: ((service = (s1.service)::text) AND ("time" >= 1459759193::bigint) AND ("time" <= 1459849193::bigint))
                           Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 2.471 ms
 Execution time: 1.269 ms
(13 rows)
```

Comment: is this a jpa or a postgresql problem?

Comment: actually i need solution in any of them.either change in postgres db or change in jpa.

Comment: What I meant was... can you remove the jpa and still have the problem?  If you can, you should remove it from the question.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: @thebjorn i have the problem even after removing jpa..So edited the question

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have edited the question. Its taking 20 seconds to get 50 rows i expect it should return it in 2-3 seconds max

Comment: use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <YOUR QUERY>` and show us the result. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/using-explain.html

Comment: You need to substitute real values in your query, and then run it in your favorite query tool (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools) -- with explain analyze..

Comment: .. in this case you might get some helpful information by substituting `select count(*)` for your first two lines (although this is purely a guess.. ;-)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thankyou for your suggestion..
Please check the edited question i have added the details

Comment: How many rows you have with `userid=10412144` and between those times? also what version are you using? and did you include the order by on that explain plan?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have edited the question again.

Comment: Whats the purpose of the `left join` if you are filtering the table `where  S2.time Between '1459759193' and '1459849193'` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Actually its sms system.in which sms receipt gets stored in same table as new rows. To join sent sms with the status message i need to use that filtering with join

Comment: @kirti `where  S2.time Between :senttime and :endtime` Referring to the S2 RTE effectively changes the left join into a plain join. Also: some composite on service and time (bad columnname, BTW) would probably help here. And the number of expected vs observed rows suggests absense of valid statistics.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, I was writing it and you did it first @joop :)

Comment: @joop Can you explain this by example:
Also: some composite on service and time would probably help here.

Comment: @kirti No I cannot. Since I am too lazy to type in the missing table definitions. BTW : the only field you retrieve from S2 is S2.time, which is just *any* time within the range that happens to exist. Do you really want that?

Comment: I think he meant a composite index on the table on both fields something like `create index idx_something on sql_sent_sms (service, time);`

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have created on time and userid, do i need on service and time as well because service parameter is being used in join and time and userid are used in filter

Comment: Just create it and run the explain, you will see if something improved if not, you delete the index.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Does it even have candidate keys, or could you pick just any pair from {user_id, service, time} ?

Comment: @joop yes table have primary key but its not being used in this query to filter or join. I needed these three (user_id, service, time) params to get my result thats why using them.

Comment: `Execution time: 1.269 ms` I think that is pretty fast, even for finding zero result rows.